# Perforce: How do I get a diff of all changed files between branches?

Tags: merge, branch, diff, perforce

I have two branches **mainline** and **rcat**. I have been working on **rcat** for a while now (multiple CLNs/Submits) and would like to merge into mainline. However, before I merge I need to submit the diff for a code review.

I want to obtain **one** unified diff between mainline and rcat branches. I have tried:

```
p4 diff2 -duw //depot/my/project/path/projectname/mainline/...  //depot/my/project/path/projectname/rcat/... >> diff.txt
```

This does not give me the files I added in rcat and also lists a bunch of unchanged files. How do I get a diff that:

1. Has changes to existing files
2. Has new files
3. Ignores unchanged files

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the teams I've worked on that used Perforce, we'd typically merge from the development branch to the mainline, then perform the code review on the pending changelist on the mainline. From your example:

```
p4 integrate //depot/my/project/path/projectname/rcat/... //depot/my/project/path/projectname/mainline/...
p4 resolve -am
# Deal with any merge conflicts
p4 diff -du > diff.txt
```

`diff.txt` will have the changes to existing files, and show deleted files as having been emptied of their contents, but won't actually show new files. (My teams used Code Collaborator to do code reviews, which handles added files.)

Alternately, if you have a Linux-like diff handy, you could try (assuming you have `mainline/...` mapped into the `mainline` directory, and `rcat/...` mapped into the `rcat` directory):

```
diff -Nur mainline rcat > diff.txt
```

which will handle deleted files and added files as you'd expect. (You may want to integrate from `mainline` to `rcat` first so the changes that show are only those that were made to `rcat`.)

Comment: I ended up doing regular diff on two directories.